# Unhandled Exception: FormatException: Unexpected character (at character 1) Flutter

Tags: php, android, flutter

I'm having a trouble why I'm getting this error
and I'm following this an old source like [like](https://github.com/idrcorner/Flutter-Login-MySQL/tree/master/android).It is possible that the syntax of old version is not the same that been using now programitically?  It would be great if anybody could figure out, thank you so much in advance!.

[image]

There are the list of error when I clicked those error in my console

*json.dart*

```
  dynamic convert(String input) => _parseJson(input, _reviver);
```

*json.dart*

```
    if (reviver == null) return decoder.convert(source);
    return JsonDecoder(reviver).convert(source);
```

*main.dart*

```
var datauser = json.decode(response.body);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're first character is a `<br>`, so it's not a json or strong, could be a 404 error html page, which can't be parsed. Double check the URL you are pinging.

Comment: thanks I just review my file and I forgot to put semi-colon thanks!

Comment: You're most welcome! If it helped you solve your problem, kindly consider marking it as the correct answer. Happy coding.